# Effect on roots when composing a polynomial with another function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Consider,

$$ p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{k=n} a_n x^n$$

if, we were to sub to compose this polynomial by putting $ x=  f(t)$ , then,

$$ p(f) =  \sum_{k=0}^{k=n} a_n (f(t) )^n$$

I know that if $ f$ is of form $ f(x) = x-\alpha$, then, all the roots of original poly gets increased by $ + \alpha$, but what if 'x' was a function of the form $ f(x) = \cos(x)$ ?  How exactly does the root get effected?

At 19:15 of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DHqCmadrw0), Michael Penn has a function involving chebbyshev polynomial and says that $ \cos \pi \frac{k}{n}$ , from what I know, the roots must be real numbers, right? then what is the sense behind saying whole functions are the roots? or am I missing something..

Comment: Well, the roots will simply be $\{t : f(t) = \alpha, \alpha \ \text{a root of} \ p\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p(r) = 0$, then $p(f(s)) = 0$ for any $s$ for which $f(s) = r$.  So the set of roots of $p \circ f$ is the preimage under $f$ of the set of roots of $p$.  (Of course, whether this is a useful statement depends on what you know about $f$ and what you're trying to do.)

> Michael Penn has a function involving chebbyshev polynomial and says
> that $\cos \pi \frac{k}{n}$ [are roots] , from what I know, the roots
> must be real numbers, right? then what is the sense behind saying
> whole functions are the roots? or am I missing something..

What's meant is that, for each integer $k$, $\cos \pi \frac{k}{n}$ is a root of the given function.  (Also, just in case, there's no need for roots to be *real* numbers -- they can be complex numbers, for instance -- but I don't think this was the point of what you were saying.)

Comment: The thing which bothers me is $ \cos \frac{\pi k}{n}$ this object gives all roots of poylnomial... I can't understand why as we vary 'k', we get all the roots

Comment: Well, that would be specific to the particular polynomial you're looking at.